# Show loop count for Qualtrics loop and merge

Tags: qualtrics

I have a block with 1 question in a Qualtrics survey that uses the loop and merge function to display 300 trials. I'm looking for a way to give some sense to the participant taking the survey how many trials they've completed or how much longer they have until they're done. The progress function in Qualtrics survey options won't work because it counts the question with 300 trials as one question (so the progress doesn't advance until they've completed all 300 trials).

Is there some way to count the number of trials that have completed in the loop & merge within a block and display it to the participant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to the question in the loop where you want to show the count and add the following to the question text:

```
${lm://CurrentLoopNumber} of ${lm://TotalLoops}
```